# Elastic Search Nested Object mapping and Query for search

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I am trying to use Elastic Search and I am stuck trying to query for the nested object.

Basically my object is of the following format

```
{
     "name" : "Some Name",
     "field2": [
          { 
            "prop1": "val1",
            "prop2": "val2"
          },
          {
             "prop1": "val3",
             "prop2":: "val4"
          }
      ]
}
```

Mapping I used for the nested field is the following.

```
PUT /someval/posts/_mapping
{
    "posts": {
       "properties": {
           "field2": {
              "type": "nested"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Say now i insert elements for /field/posts/1 and /field/posts/2 etc. I have k values for field2.prop1 and i want a query which gets the posts sorted based on most match of field2.prop1 among the K values i have. What would be the appropriate query for that. 
Also I tried a simple filter but even that doesnt seem to work right.

```
GET /someval/posts/_search
{
 "query": {
   "filtered": {
     "query": {
        "match_all": {}
     }
   },
   "filter" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "field2",
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "term" : {"field2.prop1" : "val1"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "_cache" : true
        }
    }
  } 
 }
```

The above query should match atleast the first post. But it returns no match. Can anyone help to clarify whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem in your json structure, you used filtered query , but filter(object) was in different level than query.

Find the difference.

```
POST /someval/posts/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "field2",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "field2.prop1": "val1"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "_cache": true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any debugger available for querying ? Also what would be the way to go about query for most matches in an array of objects ? Similar to the one i have posted in question

Comment: I use sense, I don't know of any. For the next part, maybe you ask as separate question so, it will be easy for other user to find it helpful .